# How do you add a Purchased Domain Name using Django need Steps

Tags: django, dns

I recently purchased a Domain Name from GoDaddy and I used Django Frameworks and have already built the site with HTML5 and CSS4 and bootstrap my problem is were do I add my custome Domain Name in Django I have looked everywhere on the web but no one seems to know 
Thanks

Comment: didn't understand.Can you elaborate more??

Comment: Sure I bought the Domain name but I built a website using Djangos Template system what i want is to add that website with the domain name i bought would I put it in the settings.py to link them together ?

Comment: you don't need to....simply just add `forwarded dns` to Godaddy account and if you type your domain then it will open your current website which it has forwarded internally.

Comment: I see what you mean but how does django know to link to the purchased domain name on godaddy like do i have to type in www.me.com into the project?

Comment: Seems like you're missing a whole step, which is finding somewhere to actually host your project on the web and deploying it there.

Comment: does not godaddy do that or would i have to seek another to host and if so who is the best for beginners using Django

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings. It can be found in your project's `settings.py` file. Usage:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com']
```

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Answer (score 0):

**I. For your development environment:**

Django includes a framework called "Sites" which enables setting the domain name and website name for your Django project through the admin interface. To enable sites, go to the settings.py script of your project and:

1. add 'django.contrib.sites' to the INSTALLED_APPS
2. at the bottom of your settings add SITE_ID = 1
3. migrate your database (open the terminal, go to the project directory, and run $ python manage.py migrate) to create the corresponding records on your database (there is no need to run $ python manage.py makemigrations)

Now you can browse to http://localhost:8000/admin/sites and edit the domain name and website name from your browser. Notice that the admin site should be previously enabled.
Once you save the changes, other django modules will make use of the new domain name and project name (for example: all email you send through an email backend will produce links using your new domain settings).

For more information, check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sites/

**II. On the production environment:**

You will need to choose your django server platform (for example: Amazon AWS EC2, IBM Cloud, Heroku, GoDaddy, etc)

You may find some guides on how to deploy your django app on these links:

- AWS: https://dev.to/rmiyazaki6499/deploying-a-production-ready-django-app-on-aws-1pk3
- IBM cloud: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/deploy-django-applications-to-ibm-cloud/
- Heroku: https://www.dothedev.com/blog/deploy-django-app-free-heroku-complete-guide/
- GoDaddy: https://www.dothedev.com/blog/2019/12/03/host-your-django-app-on-godaddy/

**III. On your domain provider:**

Most of the websites offering domain name for sale will provide you with an interface to manage the DNS (Domain Name Service) records for your domain. These records associate the IP address of your website (you should get it from your web server) to your [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)
Likewise, DNS records will associate the mail servers of your choice to your domain.

For an example on how to manage your DNS records go to: https://www.godaddy.com/help/manage-dns-records-680